I am facing a data loss for incremental soql query using a bound query for relatime updating record when i am using bulk2 jobs api
We are using salesforce bulk2 apis for getting data from salesforce basically we are facing a data loss when we are doing a incremental data capture example: I am providing two queries which we have run recently  we have run a query first on 10th select Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, RecordTypeId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, from Membership__c WHERE SystemModstamp > 2024-09-10T04:45:36.000Z which will get all the records from 10th after getting the recors we will basically find the maximum of SystemModstamp from the data and store it in this case we got it has ("2024-09-13T19:00:18.000Z") and in next run we start the query from this time stmap and my next run query is select Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, RecordTypeId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, LastActivityDate, _type__c,segment_code__c,hios_plan_id__c,ivl_membership__c,Member_cumb_id__c from Membership__c WHERE SystemModstamp > 2024-09-13T19:00:18.000Z and i got a maximum  value from data as("2024-09-14T07:14:03.000Z") this is fine but the main problem is here

In the first run example this below two records are getting updated while the api is invoked to retrieve records based on the previous last ID or systemModStamp value. This query will return all records that satisfy the condition and have already been committed but while executing this query few records are not yet committed and are getting updated so the api is not able to find the records and it is not getting the records but few other records are available and the data is getting returned till what are available and it got value as 2024-09-13T19:00:18.000Z and below two records are not yet committed to 2024-09-13T18:54:04.000Z may be the changes are  not finalized. and when i do a next run i am thinking 2024-09-13T19:00:18.000 as maximum and it is getting records from that time in the middle i am missing this realtime updating records. How can i address this. I tried to limit the query select Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, RecordTypeId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, from Membership__c WHERE ((SystemModstamp > 2024-09-10T04:45:36.000Z ) AND SystemModstamp<=current_time)) but still i am getting more records  than my current time  in systemmodstamp but i didnt face any issue while i use just bulk api version what would be the possible issue

value in my table which is not updated to 2024-09-13T18:54:04.000Z
a050a00002DDd9TAAT    2023-11-01T19:04:45.000Z
a050a000024efVEAAY  2023-11-01T19:04:45.000Z
actual value i got using just bulk api
a050a00002DDd9TAAT  2024-09-13T18:54:04.000Z
a050a000024efVEAAY  2024-09-13T18:54:04.000Z

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found some thing on stack overflow but no actual solution
We are seeing something similar at this moment. While I do not know the underlying problem, I do have a theory. Could the following be the case:
insert or update of record takes place; id is set, systemModStamp is set; the transaction is not yet committed
one or more other actions take place - that are committed
we invoke the API to retrieve records based on the previous last id or systemModStamp value; we will find all records that satistfy this condition and are already committed. We get a new (high water mark) and/or systemModStamp.
the first change that was still pending is now committed and the changed or new record becomes visible to the API
next time we invoke the API with the new or the new high watermark systemModStamp value to filter we do NOT retrieve the record - because its ID is lower (was assigned earlier) than the and/or its systemModStamp is earlier than the previous API invoke time or the high water mark value for systemModStamp.
So my theory is that the small time between the DML statement (which sets the Id and systemModStamp ) and the actual commit (which makes the record visible) (possibly combined with other transactions that start later and complete earlier) can cause this record retrieval logic to not be watertight.
We will further investigate this theory. Our workaround now will be to query with a systemModStamp value that is earlier than we would want it to be, retrieving potential duplicates (records that we have processed before) but also getting the records we are now missing out on. We need to cater for the duplicates.
